# $a \stackrel{?}{=} \langle a, b \rangle \, b + i \, \langle a, i b \rangle \, b$

Tags: complex-analysis

I read an article which claims the following identity: $a = \langle  a, b \rangle \, b + i \, \langle  a, i b \rangle \, b$. "Vectors" $a$ and $b$, here a complex number are phasors.

$\textbf{Statement}$: Given number $a \in \mathbb{C}$ and unitary vector $b \in \mathbb{C}$ i.e. $b\bar{b}=1$, does the identity $a = \langle  a, b \rangle \, b + i \, \langle  a, i b \rangle \, b$?

I am a bit tired to solve it, but you may enjoy helping me.

Comment: What's $\langle a,b\rangle$?

Comment: Assuming the standard $\langle a,b\rangle = a\bar{b}$ for a vector space $\Bbb{C}$ over $\Bbb{C}$ I get the identity equals $2a$. So what is the definition of inner product you are using?

Comment: @NinadMunshi Identifying $\mathbb{C}$ as an $\mathbb{R}$-vector space gives as standard $\langle a, b \rangle = \Re\left(a\bar{b}\right)$.  I expect that is the intended interpretation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using that $\bar b=1/b$ and with the usual interpretation of $\langle a, b \rangle = \Re\left(a\bar{b}\right)$, while noting that $\Re (-iu)=\Im u$ we get that:

$$\langle  a, b \rangle \, b + i \, \langle  a, i b \rangle \, b= (\Re (a/b)+ i\Re (-ia/b))b=$$
$$=(\Re (a/b)+ i\Im (a/b))b=(a/b)b=a$$

Comment: I was suspicious of the formula. You clarify it like a charm. Kudos.

Comment: Happy to be of help

Comment: In case your knowledge contains normed inequalities, you are welcome to take a look at: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4676915/norm-based-inequality-of-sumed-variables