# Norm-based inequality of sumed variables

Tags: normed-spaces

I read an article that claims the following inequality identity, given continuous trajectories $x(t), y(t)$:

$$\int\limits_{a}^{c} \left[(x(t)+y(t)\right]^{2} dt \stackrel{?}{\geq} \int\limits_{a}^{b} \left[\dfrac{x(t)^2}{2}-y(t)^{2}\right] dt + \int\limits_{b}^{c} \left[\dfrac{y(t)^2}{2}-x(t)^{2}\right] dt, \mbox{ for } a<b<c \in \mathbb{R}$$

I know there are norm-based inequalities, but I am unaware of this. I hope, you enjoy helping me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split the integral on the left-hand side into two integrals, one on $[a,b]$ and the other on $[b,c]$, and then apply to each integral the algebraic inequality
$$(x+y)^2 \geq \frac{x^2}2 - y^2$$
which is proven by noting
$$(x+y)^2 + y^2 - \frac{x^2}2 = \frac12 (x+2y)^2 \geq 0$$